# Why does the TreeView control collapse all the children nodes?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

When I programmatically collapse a TreeView node like this: treeView1.Nodes[0].Collapse(), all of the children nodes collapse under it, which is really annoying.  This doesn't happen when you manually click on the node to collapse it and the children nodes remember their collapsed/expanded state.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
public void Collapse(
    bool ignoreChildren
)
```

ignoreChildren
    Type: System.Boolean
    true to leave the child nodes in their current state; false to collapse the child nodes.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161262.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I should have noticed it was overloaded.